# qualifiers dropped in binding reference of type & to initializer of type const

Tags: c++

I do not understand this error & cannot find any information on it.

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <cmath>
#include "Submarine.h"
#include "Obstacle.h"

class Game : public Submarine
{
public:
    Game(unsigned w,unsigned h,bool g);
    void setKey(char Key='n');
    void update(float dt);
    void Render (const RenderWindow &Window) const ;
    static bool Collision(sf::Sprite& object1, sf::Sprite& object2);
    unsigned getWidth();
    unsigned getHeight();
    char getKey();
protected:
    bool newGame;
    unsigned width;
    unsigned height;
    char currentInput;
};
#endif
```

The error occurring here;

```
void Game::Render(const RenderWindow &Window) const
{
    sf::Sprite::Render(Window);
}
```

Error   27  error C2664: 'sf::Sprite::Render' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const sf::RenderWindow' to 'sf::RenderTarget &'

Comment: Can't you remove the `const`'s from `void Render(const RenderWindow &Window) const;`?

Answer (score 2):

`sf::Sprite::Render` takes a reference to non-const while `Window` is a reference to `const`. C++ does not allow such binding, simple as that. It would break const-correctnes.

You'll probably want to take the parameter as `RenderWindow&`.

Comment: void Game::Render(const RenderWindow& Window) const

I attempted to change it but I still get the same error, I changed it in the header file regarding the RenderWindow& too.

Comment: [`sf::Sprite::Render(RenderTarget&)`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6-fr/classsf_1_1Sprite.php#a2617aabe2aa9ce65f8f4eea8d2250bee). I'm not familiar with SFML, but compiler errors usualy don't lie. Your question doesn't have enough info to tell what's the issue.

Comment: `void Game::Render(const RenderWindow& Window) const
{
 sf::Sprite::Render(RenderTarget&);
}`
`
@jrok the error has changed but is this correct?

Comment: No. That was just a link to documentation, not a suggestion for a fix :)